# Can any object be written as a graph?

Tags: graphs, object-oriented

Lately graph theory has come into everyday practice with graph databases. So I wonder if any object can be written as a graph? I don't have the formal definition of an object, but say it is a C `struct` or a Java `Object`, isn't it so that we can express objects as graphs and that it is a more convenient and advantageous representation than an algebraic relational representation (rdbms)?

Comment: Consider a struct employee - with an employee's name, age and  id. What would be the point of representing the employee struct as a graph?

Comment: @PKG Serialization?